# How to create a dynamic textarea showing value of input slider using jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose there is an `input[type=range]`. I would like to use jQuery (or Javascript) to dynamically create a `textbox` which will show the value of the `input` when it is being changed. The `textbox` will be floating just below the `input` slider knob/arrow/dot. Also, after the value change is completed, the textbox should be automatically hidden/removed. How do I go about it?

Comment: Did you give any tries yourself?

Comment: Obviously I tried it myself. I was hoping for a generalised answer so that I can apply it in my webpage.
Some people are just eager to downvote a genuine question.

Comment: @RijurekhBose - And some people are just here to be knowledge vampires. Its a 2 way street, my friend. You put some minimal effort, we help where we can (and where you've shown some basic attempt to help yourself).

Comment: It's a very much general question, does not require any specific code.
Just a simple <input type="range" min="0" max="10"/ > would suffice for an example.
The reason why I haven't put my code is because this concept will be utilised in various sliders on my page.

Comment: @Jamiec you see Praveen Kumar's answer? I've already tried that. It's not what I want, hence I asked the question.

Comment: Against my better judgement, see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simple

```js
var isMouseDown = false;
$('#slider').mousedown(function(e){
    isMouseDown = true;
    $('#val').show().css({left:e.clientX,top:$(this).offset().top + $(this).height()}).val(this.value);
})
.mousemove(function(e){
    if(isMouseDown){
        $('#val').show().css({left:e.clientX,top:$(this).offset().top + $(this).height()}).val(this.value);
    }
})
.mouseup(function(){
    isMouseDown = false;
    $('#val').hide();
});
```

```css
#val{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    width:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100">
<input id="val" type="text">
```

You should wrap it in a [JQuery plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/) if you're going to reuse multiple times on a page

Comment: Thank you. Especially for not being sceptic about this question. Was disheartened to see downvotes to a genuine question.

Comment: @RijurekhBose - The downvotes were undoubtably due to your lack of effort, not the genuineness or otherwise of your question. I suggest you take a look around the [help] especially [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this?

```js
$(function () {
  $("#val").hide();
  $("#range").change(function () {
    $("#val").val($(this).val()).fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
/* Start Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
/* End Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */

input {display: block;}
#val {width: 25px; margin-left: 50px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="range" />
<input type="text" id="val" />
```

Comment: No, the textbox has to be just below the anchor of the slider.
Also, it is only displaying value after changing <input> value. Is there any way the textbox will show value during the change?